# Can Mercurial use a better diff tool to more efficiently store its changesets?

Tags: mercurial, diff, tortoisehg, kdiff3

I use TortoiseHg to commit changes.  The (default) diff that is shown in the commit dialog contains a lot of additions/deletions.

But in contrast when I click on the diff icon in the commit dialog,  KDiff3 opens and that comparison is a lot more 'intelligent': it detects 'better' what I changed: I moved a block of code, resulting in a lot less additions/deletions.

Since Hg "[...stores the changes needed to transform an older revision into the new revision.](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/behind-the-scenes.html)", I was wondering if I could make use of the 'intelligence' of KDiff3 to store these changes in an Hg commit?

The proposed solution in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238183/is-possible-to-change-default-diff-tool-in-mercurial) doesn't seem to apply to the TortoiseHg commit dialog.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out I misunderstood the behavior of `hg commit`.

It doesn't matter if you look at changes with the internal `hg diff` command or with KDiff3 when committing:

> Mercurial simply stores the binary
>   diff between the current version of
>   the files and the previous version of
>   the files.

At merge time however, the intelligence of KDiff3 can still be used.